# extjs textfield and special characters (& + #)

Tags: extjs, special-characters, textfield

I have a window called New Project with 2 fieldsets: Set Project Properties (which contains textfields where the user can input details such as Project Name, Project Code, etc) and Set Permissions (where the user can check/uncheck checkboxes to indicate the permission level of a given project member). Project Name and Project Code are textfields that accept space and special characters. When the user clicks on the Create Project button after filling in all the project properties and selecting the appropriate project permissions, a string is generated which is then used for Ajax request and the project is created.

However, if the user enters a project name containing the & (ampersand) character, the project is saved but the ampersand character and all characters that follow it are not saved. For example, if I input Project Name as "Testing1&56", after pressing the Create Project button, the project is created and the Project Name becomes "Testing1" (&56 is not saved/displayed). A similar thing happens when the plus (+) sign is typed in the Project Name field. After pressing the Create Project button, the project is created but the plus sign disappears and instead there is a space. For example, if I enter "Testing+Developing" as Project Name, after clicking the Create Project button, the project is created and the Project Name becomes "Testing Developing". I have alerted the params and the url to see what kind of string is generated.

I have discovered that in that string, the characters & and + are displayed. However, once the Ajax request is carried out and the project is created, the ampersand and all the characters that follow it and the plus sign are not saved in the Project Name.

Any tips on how to solve this issue would be much appreciated.

P.S. Also the pound (#) sign is not accepted in the Project Name field - I get the error message "Failed to create project" when I click the Create Project button. I would however like it to be possible for the user to enter a # sign in the Project Name field and such a project to be created when a user clicks the Create Project button.

Comment: Please use paragraphs in your text, this wall of text is almost unreadable and scares people. To make paragraphs hit enter twice or add 2 spaces at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `Post` request or use `encodeURI()` for url encoding in case of `Get` request.

Comment: I cannot use Post or Ext.urlEncode (which is now deprecated). According to my supervisor, I should be able to solve this by simply escaping the projectname and projectcode strings for &, + and #. I have been looking into Ext.String.escape(), String.search() and String.replace() but was not able to come up with a solution. I cannot modiy the Ajax (it needs to be as it is). Again, any tips as to how to proceed would be helpful.

Comment: P.S. I also just tried using encodeURIComponent(url) as I read that this escapes &,+ and #  but it gave me an error ("You are trying to decode and invalid JSON string").

Answer (score 0):

encodeURIComponent works! Where I went wrong was that I was trying to encode the params variable in its entirety (by trying encodeURIComponent(params)) whereas I should have encoded each variable (projectname, project code, etc.) separately. Here is how it's done:

```
var result = Ext.String.format("?project.ProjectName={0}&project.ProjectCode={1}&project.BaseFormatID={2}&region={3}&project.Company={4}&project.Location={5}&project.StartDate={6}&project.DeadlineDate={7}", encodeURIComponent(projectname), encodeURIComponent(projectcode), projectformat, region, encodeURIComponent(company), encodeURIComponent(location), startdate, deadlinedate);
```